# Jquery Loop though buttons at same time as text

Tags: jquery, html

I have been working on a function that loops though a list of text but failing to loop though each button at the same time, I am trying to change the backround color for each button when the corresponding text is visible.

```js
var title_scroll = (function() {
  var titleSlide = 0;

  var titleScroll = function(i) {
    var margin = '-' + (parseInt(i) * 1) + 'em';
    if (titleSlide < $('#titleScroll ul li').length - 1) {
      titleSlide++;
    } else {
      titleSlide = 0;
    }
    $('#titleScroll ul').css('margin-top', margin);
  }
  
  setInterval(function() {
    titleScroll(titleSlide)
  }, 1800);
})();
```

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#titleScroll ul {
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.hero section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero section .title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 60%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hero .title h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#titleScroll {
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#titleScroll ul {
  transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0.1, 0.25, 0.9)
}

#titleScroll li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.service-buttons li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="inline">Hi hi </h2>
<h2 id="titleScroll" class="inline">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</h2>
<h2>hi there <strong>I love:</strong></h2>
<ul id="sbuttons" class="service-buttons">
  <li id="button-1" class="sbtn">1</li>
  <li id="button-2" class="sbtn">2</li>
  <li id="button-3" class="sbtn">3</li>
  <li id="button-4" class="sbtn">4</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help?

I have been working on a function that loops though a list of text but failing to loop though each button at the same time, I am trying to change the backround color for each button when the corresponding text is visible.

Comment: Add the css here also so that the example is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight the button related to the active slide you need to know its index. You can achieve this by using the modulo operator (`%`) to get the remainder of the division between the iterative counter and the total number of slides.

Then you can use `eq()` to get the `li` and apply the class to it. Try this:

```js
var title_scroll = (function() {
  var $scrollUl = $('#titleScroll ul');
  var $buttonLi = $('#sbuttons li');
  var slideCount = $scrollUl.find('li').length;
  var titleSlide = 0;

  var titleScroll = function() {
    var activeIndex = titleSlide % slideCount;
    $scrollUl.css('margin-top', '-' + activeIndex + 'em');
    $buttonLi.removeClass('active').eq(activeIndex).addClass('active');
    titleSlide++;
    setTimeout(titleScroll, 1800);
  }

  titleScroll();
})();
```

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#titleScroll ul {
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.hero section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero section .title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 60%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hero .title h2 {
  margin: 0;
  background: olive;
}

#titleScroll {
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: olive;
}

#titleScroll ul {
  transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0.1, 0.25, 0.9);
  margin: 0;
}

#titleScroll li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.service-buttons li {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
}

.service-buttons li.active {
  background-color: olive;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title parallax" data-type="content" data-offset="90">
  <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="2250" data-aos-delay="300">
    <h2 class="inline">We Deliver </h2>
    <h2 id="titleScroll" class="inline">
      <ul>
        <li>Commercial Kitchens</li>
        <li>Air Conditioning & Ventilation</li>
        <li>HVAC</li>
        <li>Refrigeration & Cooling</li>
      </ul>
    </h2>
    <h2>Services That <strong>You Can Rely On</strong></h2>
    <ul id="sbuttons" class="service-buttons">
      <li id="button-1" class="sbtn" data-index="1">1</li>
      <li id="button-2" class="sbtn" data-index="2">2</li>
      <li id="button-3" class="sbtn">3</li>
      <li id="button-4" class="sbtn">4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```